# Derivative of cofactor matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis

In Ciarlet`s book on Mathematical Elasticity (vol. 1: Three-dimensional elasticity) on pages 39-40 we read:

> Counting the indices modulo 3, the elements of the matrix
>   $\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi$ are given by: $$
>  \left(\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi\right)_{ij}=\partial_{j+1}\varphi_{i+1}\partial_{j+2}\varphi_{i+2}-\partial_{j+2}\varphi_{i+1}\partial_{j+1}\varphi_{i+2}~~
> {\rm (no~ summation)}, $$ and a direct computation shows that $$
> \partial_{j}\left(\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi\right)_{ij}=0. $$

Above $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$, $\partial_j$ denotes its partial derivative with respect to $j$th argument.

The first element of $\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi$ is $\partial_2\varphi_2\partial_3\varphi_3-\partial_3\varphi_2\partial_2\varphi_3$, the derivative $\partial_1$ of which is
$$
\partial_{1,2}\varphi_2\partial_3\varphi_3+\partial_2\varphi_2\partial_{1,3}\varphi_3-\partial_{1,3}\varphi_2\partial_2\varphi_3-\partial_3\varphi_2\partial_{1,2}\varphi_3.
$$
I have a difficulty to understand why is it 0. Any hint or idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is, that in
$$
\partial_{j}\left(\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi\right)_{ij}=0
$$
there is summation over $j$, so, actually, instead of
$$
\partial_{1,2}\varphi_2\partial_3\varphi_3+\partial_2\varphi_2\partial_{1,3}\varphi_3-\partial_{1,3}\varphi_2\partial_2\varphi_3-\partial_3\varphi_2\partial_{1,2}\varphi_3,
$$
we have
$$
\partial_1\left(\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi\right)_{i1}+\partial_2\left(\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi\right)_{i2}+\partial_3\left(\operatorname{cof}\nabla\varphi\right)_{i3}=0.
$$